Double free when trying to free memory allocated in a Chained Hashmap in C
Apologies in advance for the code dump, I can't really think of another way to show my issue properly.
For a school project I have to make a bakery simulation and since it has to fit within certain parameters of time and space efficiency I figured the best way to implement a "recipe" system (which needs to accommodate an arbitrary amount of recipes each with an arbitrary number of ingredients listed) would be with a chained hashmap. I allocate some memory with malloc through the process, more specifically I allocate memory for each instance of the "Recipe" struct in the map, and also allocate memory for two arrays of, respectively, strings and ints, but when I try to free the memory by cycling through the hashmap I get a double free error that I can't seem to shake off no matter what I do. Here is the valgrind output.
==3362== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3362==    at 0x484988F: free (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3362==    by 0x10970E: hashClose (ChainedHashMap.c:140)
==3362==    by 0x10929E: main (ChainedHashMap.c:632)
==3362==  Address 0x1ffeffe310 is on thread 1's stack
==3362==  in frame #2, created by main (ChainedHashMap.c:604)

The hashmap works (like i imagine all c hashmaps) by using a struct as a base like so:
#define HASHSIZE_RECIPE 8
#define HASHSIZE_WAREHOUSE 15

struct Recipe
{
    char name[255]; 
    struct Recipe *p; 
    int count; 
    int *quantities; 
    char **ingredients;
};

struct Recipe *makeRecipe(char str[]) 
{
    struct Recipe *rec = malloc(sizeof(struct Recipe));

    strcpy(rec -> name, str);
    rec -> p = NULL;
    rec -> count = 0;
    rec -> quantities = NULL; 
    rec -> ingredients = NULL;

    return rec;
}

void addIng(char str[], struct Recipe *rec)
{
    if(rec -> count == 0) 
    {
        rec -> ingredients = malloc(1 * sizeof(char *));
    }
    else if(rec -> count > 0) 
    {
        rec -> ingredients = realloc(rec -> ingredients, (rec -> count +1) * sizeof(char *));
    }

    rec -> ingredients[rec -> count] = malloc(255 * sizeof(char)); 
    strcpy(rec -> ingredients[rec -> count], str); 
}

void addQuant(int qt, struct Recipe *rec) 
{
    if(rec -> count == 0)
    {
        rec -> quantities = malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
    }
    else if(rec -> count > 0)
    {
        rec -> quantities = realloc(rec -> quantities, (rec -> count +1) * sizeof(int));
    }

    rec -> quantities[rec -> count] = qt; 

    rec -> count++;
}

The code isn't commented because the comments are written in my mother tongue. I free the struct by calling this function, which seems to work on simple instances of the struct (manually created in the main function).
void deleteRecipe(struct Recipe *rec) 
{
    if(rec == NULL) //evita double free eventual
        return;

    if(rec -> ingredients != NULL) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rec -> count; i++)
        {
            free(rec -> ingredients[i]); 
            rec -> ingredients[i] = NULL;
        }

        free(rec -> ingredients); 
        rec -> ingredients = NULL;
    }

    if(rec -> quantities != NULL) 
        free(rec -> quantities); 
    rec -> quantities = NULL;

    free(rec); 
    rec = NULL;
}

Now I use a pointer to place each struct into an array and crate the chained hashMap with this function:
void hashInit(struct Recipe arr[HASHSIZE_RECIPE])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < HASHSIZE_RECIPE; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = *makeRecipe("no_recipe");
    }

}

void hashInsert(struct Recipe arr[HASHSIZE_RECIPE], struct Recipe *rec) 
{
    if(hashSearch(arr, rec -> name) < HASHSIZE_RECIPE) 
    {
        printf("%s\n", "ignored");
        return;
    }
    unsigned long i = djb2(rec -> name) % HASHSIZE_RECIPE; 
    if(strcmp(arr[i].name, "no_recipe") == 0) 
    {
        arr[i] = *rec; 
        arr[i].p = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
    struct Recipe *temp = &arr[i];

    while(temp -> p != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp -> p;
    }

    temp -> p = rec; 
    rec -> p = NULL;
    }

    printf("added\n");
}

This works without problems, only I would like to free the hashmap once the program is over, I do so with this function
void hashClose(struct Recipe arr[HASHSIZE_RECIPE])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < HASHSIZE_RECIPE; i++)
    {
        struct Recipe *delete = &arr[i];

        while (delete != NULL)
        {
            struct Recipe *temp = delete -> p; 
            deleteRecipe(delete);
            delete = temp; 
        }
    }
}

This cause a series of double free errors that I simply can't understand the cause of, the delete function should also have accounted for the possibility of freeing NULL pointers. Any pointers (get it), please?
EDIT
I didn't want to post this since its honestly a mess of a function and I think it works relatively like intended, but the mistake might indeed be here. The input for the project is delivered through a file which contains a series of instructions followed by data, with everything separated by spaces and the instructions are to use the standard input/output to handle this, so the main really only initializes a struct Recipe array, calls the initHash function on it, the closeHash function at the end, and the following inputReader function in between.
void inputReader(struct Recipe recipeBook[HASHSIZE_RECIPE])
{
    char inpt[255];
    while(gotFunct || scanf("%s", inpt) > 0) 
    {
        gotFunct = false;

        if(strcmp(inpt, "add_recipe") == 0)
        {
            if(scanf("%s", inpt) > 0) 
            {
                int quant = 0;

                struct Recipe *temp = makeRecipe(inpt);

                while(isNotAFunction(inpt)) 
                {
                    addIng(inpt, temp);
                    if(scanf("%i", &quant) > 0)
                    {addQuant(quant, temp);} 
                }

                hashInsert(recipeBook, temp); 

                gotFunct = true; 
            }

        } //(the function then proceeds with other cases, they do not cause the same issue though. 
}

This is the isNotAFunction function, it's a simple if case checker
bool isNotAFunction(char s[255])
{
    if(scanf("%s", s) > 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(s, "add_recipe") == 0 ||
           strcmp(s, "remove_recipe") == 0 ||
           strcmp(s, "delivery") == 0 ||
           strcmp(s, "order") == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false; 
    }
}

calling this with the following input should work and reproduce the issue:

Pancakes flour 150 milk 200 egg 2 sugar 30 butter 20 baking_powder 5
Smoothie banana 1 yogurt 150 honey 20 strawberry 100 orange_juice 200
Salad lettuce 100 cucumber 50 tomato 80 olive_oil 15 lemon_juice 10
feta_cheese 50 Omelette egg 3 milk 50 cheese 30 salt 5 pepper 2 butter
10 Pasta spaghetti 200 olive_oil 20 garlic 5 cherry_tomatoes 100 basil
10 parmesan 30 Sandwich bread 2 ham 50 cheese 40 lettuce 20 mayonnaise
10 tomato 30 Cookies flour 250 sugar 150 butter 100 egg 1 vanilla 5
chocolate_chips 100 Soup chicken_broth 500 carrot 50 celery 30 onion
40 salt 5 noodles 100 parsley 10


I think the error means you're attempting to free something that was not allocated via malloc() or one of its friends.  Since we don't have the code for main(), it is hard to tell what might be going wrong where — the problem is likely to be in the code you've not shown.  You need to create an MCVE, but line 600 is too large for a good MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example
— or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example
— the same idea by a different name).

Style guide: the dot . and arrow -> operators bind very tightly
because they are postfix operators.
They should not be written with spaces around them.
Writing delete -> p is not idiomatic C and indicates that the coder
is a tyro (newbie).  Use delete->p.

Are you never strcpying more than 254 characters? Why not malloc(1 + strlen(src)) instead of malloc(255)?

In void deleteRecipe(struct Recipe *rec) { … free(rec); rec = NULL; }, you set the local variable rec to null, but that has no effect whatsoever on the variable passed into the function (and so the assignment is actually pointless).  If you're relying on the variable being set null in the calling function, you've got problems.

Note that while (delete != NULL) can be written while (delete)

The valgrind output doesn't match the code.  Specifically, valgrind is stating that free is called from hashClose but the posted code doesn't do that.

You don't show the main function, but my crystal ball says the head of your list is a sentinel value containing the address of a local variable in the main function.  You can't free that.

Please post something one can compile and run, a complete piece of code.  Note that there is no such thing as a C hashmap. hash maps or hash tables are abstract data structures, key/value pairs. Can be programmed in any language. And you should not mix the hash map with your data.

Make the code shorter: In makeRecipe(), use memset(sizeof struct Recipe) instead of the assignments to 0/NULL because it's shorter and allows extension of struct Recipe. In deleteRecipe, remove all assignments to 0/NULL because they are useless. In addIng()/addQuant() only use realloc(), because it behaves the same as malloc() if its first argument is NULL. You can rewrite isNotAFunc to a one-liner: return scanf("%s", s) > 0 && (strcmp(s, "add_recipe") != 0 && ...);

By the way, this is a linked list, not a hash map. A hash uses a hashing function to convert strings into integer values.
